# sql statement - creates a view but the id column assigns every number to every title

Tags: sql, oracle

I need a little help with a statement. The view is created but instead of applying the related number_id to a description, the statement applies every number_id number to every description creating 1000s of data rows instead of 200 or so... I hope this is clear?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW MAP_SEARCH_VW
(
   number_id,
   DESCRIPTION,
   CATEGORY,
   SEARCH_DESC,
   SEARCH_TAG
)
AS
   SELECT   table1.number_id,
            table2.description,
            'Category',
            table3.search_desc,
            table3.search_tag
     FROM   table3, table2, table1
    WHERE   table3.description = table2.description;

DROP PUBLIC SYNONYM MAP_SEARCH_VW;

CREATE PUBLIC SYNONYM MAP_SEARCH_VW FOR Database.MAP_SEARCH_VW;
```

Comment: You have no `table1` in the `select` statement.  The view should fail.

Comment: Sorry, forgot this. But this does not solve the problem that its creating 1000s of rows?

Comment: It does solve the problem.  You need a join condition between the three tables.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT   table1.number_id,
         table2.description,
         'Category',
         table3.search_desc,
         table3.search_tag
  FROM   table3, table2, table1
 WHERE   table3.description = table2.description;
```

Yes, you do not specify any relation between table 1 and table 2, so *every* record of table1 gets matched with *every* record from table2.

It is more readable (and you will make less mistakes) to use *explicit* JOIN conditions like this:

```
SELECT   table1.number_id,
         table2.description,
         'Category',
         table3.search_desc,
         table3.search_tag
  FROM   table1
  JOIN   table2 on table1.somefield = table2.somefield
  JOIN   table3 on table3.description = table2.description;
```

Comment: And this is exactly why you should NEVER use implicit joins. You have an accidental cross join. Write explict joins and the problem is solved. Implicit joins are a sql antipattern, it is a poor practice to use them under any circumstances eccept when you have a really old datbase that won't accept explicit joins.